# How to know if a String contains a specific set of characters in Java

Tags: java, string

I got a String which can contain:

- plain text (a reply for a question or an email for example);
- only numbers and "=";
- only numbers and "[" "]" ",".

I am trying to find a way to discriminate among those cases and, in particular, to be able to know if that String belongs ONLY to one case (i.e. if it contains plain text and numbers and other characters like "=" or "[" I'd like to put it in the first case, while if it contains ONLY number and "=" I'd like to put it in the second case).

I tried using something like:

```
if (text.contains("[") && text.contains("]") && text.contains(","))
      //other code
```

but in this case it could be both text and those characters or number and those characters, so I can't decide if I'm in the first or second case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Look into regexes -- specifically the "character class" features.

Comment: You should use '&&' i stead of '&'

Comment: Well, the question is too broad. Please try to solve each task separately. *Formulate the requirements precisely*. Come back if you have trouble.

Comment: I'll take a look into those regexes, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be solved by using regex. Take a look [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

In your case: here are the regexes I would use:

only numbers and "=";

```
s.matches("[0-9|=]+");
```

only numbers and "[" "]" ",".

```
s.matches("[0-9\\[\\],]+");
```

And the first case is all the rest!

```
!s.isEmpty();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The second one though shows me an error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\).

Comment: that's weird. maybe try around on refiddle. Here is my guess: http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5995c7d875622d0c24250000

Answer (score 3):

Go for regex

For numbers:

```
System.out.println(data.matches("[0-9]+"));
```

For numbers and '='

```
System.out.println(data.matches("[0-9=]+"));
```

For numbers and square brackets and ,

```
System.out.println(data.matches("[0-9\\[\\],]+") );
```

For plain text:

```
   System.out.println(data.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

where `data` is your input text